# C++: Does this look like memory fragmentation?

Tags: c++, memory-management, quadtree, memory-fragmentation

SUMMARY:

I have an application which consumes way more memory that it should (roughly about 250% of the expected amount) but I can't seem to find any memory leaks. Calling the same function (which does a lot of allocations) will keep increasing memory usage to some point and then it will not change and stay there.

PROGRAM DETAILS:

The application uses a quadtree data structure to store 'Points'. It is possible to specify the maximum number of points to be stored in memory (cache size). The 'Points' are stored in 'PointBuckets' (arrays of points linked to the leaf nodes of the quadtree) which, if the maximum total number of points in the quadtree is reached, are serialized and saved to temporary files, to be retrieved when needed. This all seems to work fine.

Now when a file is loaded a new Quadtree is created and the old one is deleted if it exists, then points are read from the file and inserted into the quadtree one by one. A lot of memory allocations take place as buckets are being created and deleted during node splitting etc.

SYMPTOMS:

If I load a file that is expected to use 300MB of memory once, I get the expected amount of memory consumed. All good. If I keep loading the same file over and over again the memory usage keeps growing (I'm looking at the RES column in top, Linux) till about 700MB. That could indicate a memory leak. However if I then keep loading the files still, memory consumption just stays at 700MB.

Another thing: When I use valgrind massif and look at the memory usage it always stays within expected limit. For example if I specify cache size to be 1.5 GB and run my program alone, it will eventually consume 4GB of memory. If I run it in massif, it will stay below 2GB for all the time and then in the produced graphs I'll be able to see that it in fact never allocated more then the expected 1.5GB. My naive assumption is that this happens because massif uses a custom memory pool which somehow prevents fragmentation.

So what do you think is going on here? What kind of solution should I look for to solve this issue, if it is memory fragmentation?

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak to me... does using just `valgrind` report any lost memory?

Comment: he already said valgrind shows no leak

Comment: @nhed (s)he said massif didn't show the memory gain, but valgrind alone would report leaks.

Comment: If it was a memory leak, wouldn't it be continuous? Would't the memory usage keep growing indefinitely rather than settle at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put it more at simple allocator and OS caching behaviours. They retain memory you allocated instead of freeing it so that it can be returned to you in a more prompt fashion the next time you request it. However, 250% does sound like a lot for this kind of effect- you could be looking at fragmentation problems.

Try swapping your allocator for a fragmentation-free allocator like object pool or memory arena.

Comment: Great, jemalloc has fixed the issue. I'm surprised how well it works!